# Python Boto3 - data isn't being written to DynamoDB properly

Tags: python, xml, amazon-dynamodb

I have an XML file I am parsing strings from with Python and writing to a DynamoDB table in AWS. The tags are `<IMAGE_ID>` and `<CVSS_FINAL>`. When I loop through and `print()` these values, it returns all of them. However, when I write to Dynamo, only one row of data is written. So, I don't understand why `print()` returns everything, but only one row is written to the datastore.

**Code:**

```
import boto3
import lxml
from lxml import etree

def WriteItemToTable():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = ‘xxxxxxxxxxxx’
    key = 'vuln_data.xml'
    dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb')

    obj = s3.Object(‘xxxxxxxxxx’, 'vuln_data.xml')
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()

    image_id = etree.fromstring(body).findall('HOST_LIST/HOST/EC2_INFO/IMAGE_ID')
    risk_score = etree.fromstring(body).findall('HOST_LIST/HOST/VULN_INFO_LIST/VULN_INFO/CVSS_FINAL')

    for el in image_id:
        i = el.text
        print(i)

    for el in risk_score:
        j = el.text
        print(j)

    response = dynamo.put_item(
    TableName='ExistingAMI',
        Item={
            'AMI_ID': {
                'S': i
             },
            'CVSS_SCORE': {
                'S': j
            },
         }
       )

WriteItemToTable()
```

**XML:**

```
<HOST_LIST>
    <HOST>
      <EC2_INFO>
        <PUBLIC_DNS_NAME><![CDATA[ec2-xxxxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com]]></PUBLIC_DNS_NAME>
        <IMAGE_ID><![CDATA[ami-xxxxxx]]></IMAGE_ID>
      </EC2_INFO>
      <OPERATING_SYSTEM><![CDATA[Linux x.y]]></OPERATING_SYSTEM>
      <VULN_INFO_LIST>
        <VULN_INFO>
          <QID id="qid_x”>x</QID>
          <TYPE>Vuln</TYPE>
          <CVSS_FINAL>3.5</CVSS_FINAL>
          <RESULT><![CDATA[TLSv1.0 is supported]]></RESULT>
        </VULN_INFO>
        <VULN_INFO>
      <QID id="qid_xxxx">xxxxx</QID>
      <CVSS_FINAL>2.1</CVSS_FINAL>
    </VULN_INFO>
    <VULN_INFO>
      <QID id="qid_xxxx">xxxx</QID>
      <CVSS_FINAL>4.3</CVSS_FINAL>
      <RESULT><![CDATA[TLSv1.0 is supported]]></RESULT>
    </VULN_INFO>
    </VULN_INFO_LIST>
    </HOST>
    <HOST>
      <EC2_INFO>
        <PUBLIC_DNS_NAME><![CDATA[ec2-xxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com]]></PUBLIC_DNS_NAME>
        <IMAGE_ID><![CDATA[ami-yyyyyy]]></IMAGE_ID>
      </EC2_INFO>
      <OPERATING_SYSTEM><![CDATA[Amazon Linux]]></OPERATING_SYSTEM>
      <VULN_INFO_LIST>
        <VULN_INFO>
          <QID id=“x”>x</QID>
          <CVSS_FINAL>3.6</CVSS_FINAL>
        </VULN_INFO>
    </VULN_INFO_LIST>
    </HOST>
</HOST_LIST>
```

**print() output:**

```
ami-xxxxxx
ami-yyyyyy
3.5
3.6
```

**Dynamo Table:**

[Dynamo Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDJW7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I know nothing of DynamoDB, your Python code should only pass one *i* and *j* value as your `dynamo.put_item` block of code is not nested in either of the `for` loops and hence takes their last assigned values.

Simply run your *image_id* and *risk_score* search together in one loop which can be nested at the `<HOST>` level. And consider `xpath()`, available in `lxml`. And no need for the `import lxml` call as you import its method `etree` instead.

```
doc = etree.fromstring(body)  # PARSE ONLY ONCE

hosts = doc.xpath('//HOST')

for h in hosts:
    i = h.xpath('EC2_INFO/IMAGE_ID')[0].text
    print(i)

    j = h.xpath('VULN_INFO_LIST/VULN_INFO/CVSS_FINAL')[0].text
    print(j)

    response = dynamo.put_item(
        TableName='ExistingAMI',
        Item={
            'AMI_ID': {
                 'S': i
             },
            'CVSS_SCORE': {
                'S': j
            },
         }
    )

WriteItemToTable()

# ami-xxxxxx
# 3.5
# ami-yyyyyy
# 3.6
```

---

For multiple *CVSS_FINAL*, use XPath to parse down to the `<CSVSS_FINAL>` then retrieve corresponding *IMAGE_ID* with `ancestor::*`

```
cvss = obj.xpath('//CVSS_FINAL')   # ALL CVSS_FINAL NODES

for c in cvss:        
    i = c.xpath('ancestor::HOST/EC2_INFO/IMAGE_ID')[0].text
    print(i)

    j = c.text
    print(j)

    k = c.xpath('concat(following-sibling::RESULT, "")')
    print(k)

    response = dynamo.put_item( ... )

# ami-xxxxxx
# 3.5
# TLSv1.0 is supported
# ami-xxxxxx
# 2.1
# 
# ami-xxxxxx
# 4.3
# TLSv1.0 is supported
# ami-yyyyyy
# 3.6
#
```

Comment: The logic here is clear. However, it only returns the first assigned value. I.e. `ami-xxxxx`, `3.5`

Comment: Returns? Do you mean print outs or writes to your DynamoDB? Are you absolutely sure your current XML is same as posted in your question? Maybe there is only one `<HOST>` in your test version? I just checked and the print out of both pairs in my answer does render.

Comment: My apologies, prints out. There was a typo in my script. It works great! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how I could do this if say there were multiple <CVSS_FINAL> tags nested within one <HOST> tag? I have updated the XML in the question to reflect this.

Comment: Glad it worked out. See update using `xpath` to find all `<CVSS_FINAL>` nodes and retrieve corresponding `<IMAGE_ID>` in above parent location.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you. But, how could I do this with an additional node `<RESULT>` that also appears several times. Updated in the `XML` (node right below `<CVSS_FINAL>`).

Comment: See updated with new *k* variable using `following-sibling` and `concat()` for optional elements since *RESULT* is missing for some. And try learning XPath with `ancestor::*`, `following-sibling::*`, `preceding-sibling::*`, or long format, `/grandparent/parent/child/grandchild`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I will look through the documentation.